# The persimmon jam makes my tongue dry

Tags: fruit, jam

I made a persimmon jam, just like I successfully made other jams, i.e.: took 7 persimmons, added a cup of sugar and a little lemon juice, put in a bread baker and activated the special jam program.

The jam is delicious, but, after several seconds in the mouth, it gives a very unpleasant feeling that the tongue and the entire mouth becomes dry.

What happened to the jam? Is there a way to rescue it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like the persimmons (or one of the persimmons) were not quite ripe enough.

> When you eat an unripe astringent persimmon (American or Asian) the
>   mouth immediately draws up.  Sometimes you'll get a hint of sweetness
>   (if it is near-ripe) but the mouth-feel is immediate.  Tannins in
>   persimmons make your tongue, cheeks, and gums feel as though you're
>   chewing on a cross between aspirin, alum, and chalk.  Your tongue
>   almost feels like a fine sandpaper. *[Judging the Ripeness of Persimmons](http://www.persimmonpudding.com/harvest/ripeness.html)*

Unfortunately, I think that specific batch of jam can't be salvaged -- I don't know any way to "ripen" a persimmon if it's already been cooked into something. Next time you try this, taste a small bit of each fruit first to see if they're ripe enough.

Comment: Is this dangerous? Or just untasty?

Comment: And this is why I hate persimmons.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi Wikipedia indicates that a [phytobezoar can form in your stomach if you eat unripe persimmons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persimmon#Unripened_persimmons), but also states this "should not be of concern when consuming moderate quantities of persimmons" -- so it isn't _risk-free_, but is probably very low risk (although [higher for individuals with certain medical conditions](http://www.persimmonpudding.com/bezoars.html)). I wouldn't worry that you've already eaten some.

Comment: It sounds like you'd know if you were at risk - you'd be eating a *lot* of persimmons and if they're just mildly unripe, there's not as much tannin.